# Using libVLC media_list instead of a media_player to play a directory of songs

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to use `libVLC` v2 `C` bindings in order to play all the songs (`mp3`/`m4a`/`ogg`)s inside a directory given its path.

I'm currently only using the module **`libvlc_media_player`**, with methods like `libvlc_media_player_set_media` to set a song from a given path.

I see there is a [module](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__list.html) called `libvlc_media_list`, with `libvlc_media_list_set_media`.

What is a `libvlc_media_list` and how do I set it with a path to a directory (with several audio files inside)? The `libvlc_media_list_player` takes a `libvlc_media_player`, but I do not know where to set the media (path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`media_list` is used to play `play lists`(.pls .m3u etc) as opposed to individual files.
Not sure about `c` but in python:

```
Media_list = Instance.media_list_new([url])
list_player = Instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(Media_list)
list_player.play()
```

as opposed to:

```
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(url)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

for an individual file.
I hope that you can pick the bones out of the above.
For your purposes, it looks like you need to use the individual file option, using a url list, whilst looping over the list.

Again (apologies) in python:

```
import vlc
import time
my_list = ['vp1.mp3','happy.mp3']
instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
playing = set([1,2,3,4])
for i in my_list:
    player.set_mrl(i)
    player.play()
    play=True
    while play == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        play_state = player.get_state()
        if play_state in playing:
            continue
        else:
            play = False
```

Comment: So the solution you give, instead of using a list_player, is to loop over a list and play each song individually, can I set it somehow to play the next song when the first is finished playing?

Comment: See very simple example added to the answer

Comment: thanks a lot, that's great! And python's no problem, in fact, probably better that way :P