# Implement previous with libvlc playback

Tags: go, channel, libvlc, tui

I'm using `libvlc` (go binding) to play music in a TUI. Instead of using the `media_list_player`, which has `Next` and `Previous` methods, I followed the advice of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44647523/4443226 to use the regular `media_player` and a loop:

```py
import vlc
import time
my_list = ['vp1.mp3','happy.mp3']
instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
playing = set([1,2,3,4])
for i in my_list:
    player.set_mrl(i)
    player.play()
    play=True
    while play == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        play_state = player.get_state()
        if play_state in playing:
            continue
        else:
            play = False
```

This has the benefit that I can get the index of the current song and I can get the *position* and *duration* of the current playing song.

I implemented it in Go, and one of the problems, is that I am unable to implement (effectively) `Next` and `Previous` song.

Part of the problem is that this playback loop must be in a **separate `goroutine`** than the UI thread. I use `chan` to send signals for stopping the `goroutine` and skipping the song.

```golang
func playAlbum(p *vlc.Player, a Album, l *tui.List, s *tui.StatusBar, done, next, prev chan struct{}) (err error) {
    playlist := make([]*vlc.Media, 0)
    for _, path := range a.Paths {
        media, err := vlc.NewMediaFromPath(path)
        // check eturn err
        playlist = append(playlist, media)
    }

    for idx := range playlist {
        p.SetMedia(playlist[idx])
        err = p.Play()
        // check return err

        status, err := p.MediaState()
        // check return err

    PlaybackLoop:
        for status != vlc.MediaEnded {
            status, err = p.MediaState()
            // continue with err

            l.SetSelected(idx) // TUI list of songs

            song := songStatus(a, l.Selected())
            s.SetPermanentText(song) // TUI status bar

            select {
            case <-next:
                break PlaybackLoop
            case <-prev:
                continue // TODO: implement previous
            case <-done:
                return err
            default:
                time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
            }
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

I am unable to implement `Previous`, because I can't just go back in the for loop.

Ideally I think I would like to use the `libvlc` `media_list_player`. However, if I can't get the song **duration** and **length** as well as the **index** of the song in the `media_list`, I would rather do this method.

If I must use the `media_player` instead, is there a better way to handle playback than using nested loops and channels? Something that can use **previous**?

Comment: For previous you can probably create some data structure that stores "prev", "current", "next" kinda like a simple linked list. I'm sure there are many examples if your having trouble implementing your own.. He's the one of the first hits on Google https://gist.github.com/f76f69198395d18338887a60fb08c7fait would have to mod to the nodes to store values of type `media`.. Whatever that type is. I suggest something like a linked list because they can be transversed forward and backwards.

Comment: Otherwise if the linked list route is not something you see yourself implementing or using you'll have to keep track of the index of the currently running song so that you decrement it and get the previous item. In my opinion it's more book keeping... This is a better example as it is safe for concurrency http://0xax.blogspot.com/2014/08/thread-safe-linked-list-for-golang.html?m=1

Comment: A linked list, or thread-safe list are excellent ideas! Thanks, but how would I then go about iterating through the list? And going _back_ at some point while iterating through the list?

Comment: In the second link I sent you http://0xax.blogspot.com/2014/08/thread-safe-linked-list-for-golang.html the next and prev methods have been defined already. I imagine that they can be used in someway. You can call next in a forever loop `for {if{ next is nil break} }` and you can send prev on a channel like you send next because it's already knows what current is. It might mean you change some of your current logic. Start by init the linked list. Play the first song in the linked list. If next is hit send the channel, call next, ditto with prev. Remove your range Playlist loop, not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and discussion with the OP It was determined that a linked list was probably the best route in trying to control how to go forward and backwards with a bit less effort. Since Go is being used and the modules that are being used require goroutines the linked list also would have to be safe to use within goroutines.