# how can i play multiple songs[list of songs] in one go and have access to stop them also in python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, operating-system, vlc

I have done it using os module but I can't stop the song there. then I use VLC module but it's only applicable for one song only. please help

elif 'music' in query:

```
music_dir = 'D:\\my songs\\my songs'
songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
random.shuffle(songs)
os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir,songs[0]))
```

I want to play all the songs .its working but how to stop songs when its playing

Comment: You need to post the code that you have written so far, so that we can see where you are going wrong. It will also help us to gauge how answers should be framed. Edit your question.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229378/using-libvlc-media-list-instead-of-a-media-player-to-play-a-directory-of-songs/44647523#44647523

Comment: Admittedly it's linux bash shell but there must be a way of duplicating in windows, the simplest method is to do no coding at all, just bang this onto the command line `for i in './vp1.mp3' './happy.mp3'; do python vlc.py $i;done`